# Uno Platform: How to determine which nuget packages are needed for each platform

Tags: nuget, uno-platform

I think I have messed up which nuget packages are installed for my various platforms, and which versions are appropriate. How does one determine the correct packages and versions?

I discovered this by creating a fresh solution and comparing some of the package assignments and versions between that and my "real" solution.

Currently, my UWP build is failing with

```
CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IMainPage_Bindings' could not be found
```

Here are a couple of my packages:

```
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.9 for UWP only
NetStandard.Library                        2.0.3 for Wasm and UWP
```

I will make a 2nd pass and try to get all my packages the same as for my "fresh" app, but my question still stands: how am I to determine the correct package version and assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of scenario, it is best to start from the original templates.

You can either:

- Create a new Uno application from the templates
- Take a look at the [template files from the GitHub repository](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/tree/master/src/SolutionTemplate/UnoSolutionTemplate)

Then observe the differences between those files and your project and align the versions.

Comment: And, that's what I ended up doing. I think the getting-started instructions need to say something about this. After creating a project, I noticed some of the packages didn't get installed for all heads. I had also read in numerous places that I should be sure that the same package version is installed for all projects. So I thought something had gone wrong and meticulously updated all of them. Of course, now I know, that broke it :)